# umlauts and symbols in Jmeter

Tags: http, csv, testing, jmeter, symbols

I want to make a simple HTTP-Request in JMeter. I'm using some variables of a CSV I just created. In this CSV are names like "Müller" or "Böhm".

So when I run the test I notice that Jmeter convert "Müller" into "MÃÂ¼ller".

I create my CSV in Notepad++ (UTF-8 without BOM).

Furthermore I change Jmeter.properties:

> sampleresult.default.encoding=UTF-8

An other idea was to use the post-Benshellsampler:

> prev.setDataEncoding("UTF-8");

and

> request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

None of these worked for me.

Errorreport: http://pastebin.com/EydAjfdm

JMeter: 2.13 |
Plugins: Webdriver, Standard, Extra, ExtraLibs (1.3.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My expectation is that you need to change encoding of JVM. Add the following line:

```
log.info(System.getProperty("file.encoding") + " <--------------------");
```

to any Beanshell Test Element and look into *jmeter.log* file. If you see something other than `UTF-8` - you have a problem which needs to be fixed

```
2015/12/15 19:05:37 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: UTF-8 <--------------------
```

---

1. Remove all Beanshell tweaks (by the way, the one with `request` won't work)
2. Add the following line to *system.properties* file (lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   file.encoding=UTF-8
   ```
3. Restart JMeter and that should be it.

See:

- [List of Java system properties](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_61/rzaha/sysprop2.htm) in general and `file.encoding` bit in particular
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) - to learn more about different JMeter properties types and ways of working with them

Comment: You are right. I got this:
jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: Cp1252 <-------------------- 
So I add the line to jmeter.properties and restart jmeter but nothing happend. In log.file is still Cp1252. 
jmeter.properties: http://pastebin.com/3B61Yd6W

Comment: So I tried with commandline and that worked for me.
Now it looks like that:  jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: UTF8 <--------------------
But I still got "MÃÂ¼ller" than "Müller" in my test.

Comment: "jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: UTF8 <-------------------- But I still got "MÃÂ¼ller" than "Müller" in my test"   Yay, same here. Did you find any solution for this problem?